# How run gtest and make sure sigabrt never happens

Tags: c++, googletest, sigabrt

I need a gtest that will pass if sigabrt doesn't happen, but need to know if it does happen, or fail the test.  How would I do that?

I was thinking of this sort of thing:

```
TEST_F(TestTest, testSigabrtDoesntHappen)
{
   MyObject &myObject = MyObject::instance();
   for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
        myObject.doWork(); //this will sigabrt on the second try, if at all
        ASSERT_TRUE(myObject);
   }
   ASSERT_TRUE(myObject);
}
```

So assuming a sigabrt would exit out of the test if it occurs, then we would get 3 test passes otherwise.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Not on Window:**

```
::testing::KilledBySignal(signal_number)  // Not available on Windows.
```

You should look the [guide](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md).

It seems like that for me (not tested) :

```
TEST_F(TestTest, testSigabrtDoesntHappen)
{
   MyObject &myObject = MyObject::instance();
   for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
        EXPECT_EXIT(myObject.doWork(), ::testing::KilledBySignal(SIGBART)), "Regex to match error message");
        ASSERT_TRUE(myObject);
   }
   ASSERT_TRUE(myObject);
}
```

**On Window:**

You'll have to handle signal yourself with this kind of code:

```
// crt_signal.c  
// compile with: /EHsc /W4  
// Use signal to attach a signal handler to the abort routine  
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <signal.h>  
#include <tchar.h>  

void SignalHandler(int signal)  
{  
    if (signal == SIGABRT) {  
        // abort signal handler code  
    } else {  
        // ...  
    }  
}  

int main()  
{  
    typedef void (*SignalHandlerPointer)(int);  

    SignalHandlerPointer previousHandler;  
    previousHandler = signal(SIGABRT, SignalHandler);  

    abort();  //emit SIGBART ?
}
```

[doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdkz3x12.aspx)

But seriously if you have one time get a SIGBART running your code, there are some problems with your code that you have to remove before release the software.

---

But if you really want to debug your code (with googletest), use this with your debugger:

```
foo_test --gtest_repeat=1000 --gtest_break_on_failure
```

You can add others option to it, again : check the doc :)

Comment: Mine is windows, mac, linux so I can't do the KilledBySignal?

Comment: @Michele signal on window are a mess (in fact I was thinking they didn't exist), I think GoogleTest will never support that code on Window sorry.

Comment: Maybe I can just run the test if we're not windows.  I like your idea, though.  I've seen the link for the guide, but it's tough to apply it to what I'm doing.

Comment: It's only sometimes that we would expect it to exit with the sigabrt when I call doWork.  Do you know of something that works better than EXPECT_EXIT?

Comment: @Michele signal are os specific and I don't work on Window sorry. But why your function throw SIGBART sometimes? It's a behavior that you decided? If not unit test are not the solution.

Comment: They had someone say that once they got a sigabrt and wanted to test to make sure they weren't getting them.

Comment: @Michele well I just add a window example for how handle signal. Hope it'll help.

Comment: I'm still not sure KilledBySignal will do the trick.  It only happens sometimes that we get the sigabrt.  So the test would fail most of the time if I EXPECT_EXIT.

Comment: @Michele you're right I should have put !(::testing::KilledBySignal(SIGBART)), didn't find EXPECT_NO_EXIT on the doc.

Comment: I'm not sure what to use if there's no expect_no_exit

Comment: @Michele Look at my last comment and my edit. There is way to much comments there.

Comment: You think putting !(::testing::killedbysignal(sigabrt)) works with expect_exit?

Comment: The doc said that ::testing::KilledBySignal(SIGBART) is a predicate which return true if the signal is throw. And EXPECT_EXIT is waiting a predicate. You may have to create another bool fun(), but it's the idea yes.

Comment: The test failed to die, since it's only happening sometimes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130237/discussion-between-mathieu-van-nevel-and-michele).

Comment: I wound up testing for the positive case so if it sigabrt, the test fails: ASSERT_NO_THROW({
            myObject.doWork(); 
        }); Then ran the gtest at the linux command line: bash, source path file, ./pathfile.sh, UnitTest_debug_outputFile --gtest_repeat=1000 --gtest_break_on_failure  --gtest_filter="testName*"

Comment: You don't need ASSERT_NO_THROW, that's for catching exception. Just run your test in a normal way. But you need to run it inside the debugger, like gdb.